# Firefox extension addon tab using background script

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a firefox extension that opens up a tab with a html file that is located in my data folder. The main.js does this:

```
 function handleClick(state) {
   tabs.open("login.html");
  }
```

In main.js I require() a bunch of scripts to run as background scripts. This html file acts as the "login" for the extension. How can this html page have access to the background scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't. You'll need to attach a content script to your login page and to send variables to it the standard way [using port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port).

Also, does your code work? Don't you need to [`require(sdk/self).data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data) to get access to `login.html`?

Here's an example of what you can do.

**main.js**

```
const { data } = require('sdk/self');

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open({
    url: data.url('login.html'),
    onOpen: function(tab) {
      var worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: data.url('login.js')
      });
      worker.port.emit('foo', foo);
      worker.port.on('bar', handleBar);
    }
  });
}

function handleBar(bar) {
  // do something with bar;
}
```

**login.js**

```
self.port.on('foo', function(foo) {
  // do something with foo
});

self.port.emit('bar', bar);
```

Comment: It does open the html page. 

Ok thanks I will try this. I'm basically trying to mimic the chrome extension "options" page. Since I am trying to port an extension.

Comment: I wouldn't try to mimic. Firefox has its own [simple prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) module for this. It will create an options page for you in the addons manager.

Comment: Hm so the Chrome extension has a custom login page, and when logged in has like a manager page where you can do a bunch of stuff. I tried out the simple prefs but it doesn't seem like this type of thing will be possible with it?

Comment: You can just open your own prefs page using tabs.open, as you suggest. There is a limitation however - any JS files that are used by your options page need to be located in the ./data/ directory. An html page served from ./data can refer to any other files (images, css, js) via relative paths. Think of ./data the same way you would ./public in a web project.

Comment: In my chrome "options" page it includes javascript files using the regular <script> tags but in those scripts it does stuff like. chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(). For firefox I need to pass these using port?

Comment: Actually, see @canuckistani comment, if you open a page from your data folder, I think it has the privileges to use privileged code. It sounds feasible to me, in bootstrap thats how it is, if you open a privileged page it has privileged script access. So for your options page you don't need to use port. MAYBE, im not an sdk guy. But if you want to see how to make options page non-sdk way here: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/options-xhtml install that repo with this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ this demo also shows easy localization.

Comment: No, all JS code in the data folder is run in a sandbox that has no access to privileged code. Please read [SDK docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Content_Processes) before commenting on SDK questions.